# CUDA error: Invalid configuration argument

Tags: c, cuda

Hi I have the following CUDA C code:

kernel.cu:

```
/******************************************************************************
 *cr
 ******************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>

#define TILE_SIZE 16
#define BLOCK_SIZE 512


/****************************************************************/
// Kernel for matrix multiplication: 
// A: m x n matrix 
// B: n x k matrix
// C = A x B: m x k matrix
__global__ void mysgemm(int m, int n, int k, const double *A, const double *B, double* C) {

    __shared__ float ds_A[TILE_SIZE][TILE_SIZE];
    __shared__ float ds_B[TILE_SIZE][TILE_SIZE];

    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int by = blockIdx.y;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;
    int row = (by*TILE_SIZE+ty);//%m;
    int col = (bx*TILE_SIZE+tx);//%n;
    float pvalue = 0;


    for(int i=0;i<(k-1)/TILE_SIZE+1;++i)
    {
        if((i*TILE_SIZE +tx < k) && (row < m))
            ds_A[ty][tx] = A[row*k+i*TILE_SIZE+tx];
        else ds_A[ty][tx] = 0;

        if((i*TILE_SIZE+ty < k) && (col < n)) 
            ds_B[ty][tx] = B[(i*TILE_SIZE+ty)*n+col];       // Load data into shared memory
        else ds_B[ty][tx] = 0;

        __syncthreads();

        if(row < m && col < n)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<TILE_SIZE;++j)
            {
                //if(j < k)
                    pvalue += ds_A[ty][j]*ds_B[j][tx];
            }
            }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    if(row < m && col < n)
        C[row*n+col] = pvalue;
}
/****************************************************************/


/****************************************************************/
// Kernel to multiply each element in A by the corresponding element in B and store 
// the result to the corresponding element in C. All vectors should be of length m
__global__ void elem_mul(int m, const double *A, const double *B, double* C) 
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int i = tx+bx*blockDim.x; 
    if(i < m)
        C[i] = A[i]*B[i];
}
/****************************************************************/

/****************************************************************/
// Kernel for parallel sum
__global__ void reduction(double *out, double *in, unsigned size)
{
    __shared__ float partialSum[2*BLOCK_SIZE];
    unsigned int t = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int start = 2*blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

    if(start + t >= size)
        partialSum[t] = 0;
    else partialSum[t] = in[start+t];

    if(start + blockDim.x+t>= size)
        partialSum[blockDim.x+t] = 0;
    else partialSum[blockDim.x+t] = in[start + blockDim.x+t];

    for(unsigned int stride = 1; stride <=blockDim.x; stride*=2)
    {
        __syncthreads();
        if(t % stride ==0)
            partialSum[2*t]+=partialSum[2*t+stride];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    out[blockIdx.x] = partialSum[0];
}
/****************************************************************/


/****************************************************************/
// Uses several kernels to compute the inner product of A and B
void inner_product(double *out, int m, const double *A, const double* B, double* temp)
{
    dim3    dimGrid((m-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,(m-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,1);
    dim3    dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE,1);

    elem_mul<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(m,A,B,temp);
    reduction<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(out,temp,m);        
}
/****************************************************************/

// Kernel to multiply each element in the matrix out in the following manner:
// out(i,j) = in(i) - in(j)
__global__ void fill(int m, const double *in, double *out) 
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int by = blockIdx.y;    
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;

    int i = tx+bx*blockDim.x; 
    int j = ty+by*blockDim.y; 

    if((i < m) && (j < m))
        out[i*m+j] = in[i]-in[j];
}

// Kernel to fill the matrix out with the formula out(i,j) = exp(-omega*T(i.j))
__global__ void fill_E(int m, double coeff, double *in, double *out) 
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;       
    int i = tx+bx*blockDim.x; 

    if(i < m)
        out[i] = exp(-coeff * in[i]);
}

// Kernel for scalar multiplication for an mxk matirx and a coefficient coeff
__global__ void scal_mul(int m, int k, double coeff, double *in, double *out) 
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;       
    int i = tx+bx*blockDim.x; 

    if(i < m*k)
        out[i] = coeff * in[i];
}

// Kernel for scalar multiplication for an mxk matirx and a coefficient coeff
__global__ void scal_add(int m, int k, double coeff, double *in, double *out) 
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;       
    int i = tx+bx*blockDim.x; 

    if(i < m*k)
        out[i] = coeff + in[i];
}


/****************************************************************/
// Kernel to update vector p2
__global__ void update_p2(int m, double coeff, double *in, double *out) 
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;       
    int i = tx+bx*blockDim.x; 

    if(i < m)
        out[i] = coeff/in[i];
}
/****************************************************************/


/****************************************************************/
// Kernel to update matrix p
__global__ void update_p(int m, double* p2, double *denom, double *num, double *out) 
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;       
    int i = tx+bx*blockDim.x; 

    // loop through columns j
    for(int j=0; j<m; ++j)
    {
        if(i == j)
            out[i*m + j] = p2[i];
        else if(i < m)
            out[i*m + j] = num[i*m+j]/denom[i];
    }
}
/****************************************************************/


/****************************************************************/
// Kernel to update the error, counter, and parameter variables
__global__ void update(int* counter, double* error, double *mu, double *mu_temp, double* alpha, double* alpha_temp, double* omega, double* omega_temp) 
{   
    *counter = *counter + 1;
    *error = (mu - mu_temp)*(mu - mu_temp) + (alpha-alpha_temp)*(alpha-alpha_temp) + (omega-omega_temp)*(omega-omega_temp);
    mu = mu_temp;
    alpha = alpha_temp;
    omega = omega_temp; 
}
/****************************************************************/


/****************************************************************/
// Kernel to assign old * coeff + inc to new
__global__ void assign(double* n, double* old, double coeff, double inc)
{
    //*n = (*old)*coeff + inc;
    *n = 5.0;
}
/****************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************************************/
// Function to calibrate the 1-D Hawke's process. Does so via an iterative procedure. Variables:
// int size:  length of the Time-series vectors. Also the number of rows and columns in input matrices
// double mu:       One of three parameters calibrated
// double alpha:    One of three parameters calibrated
// double omega:    One of three parameters calibrated
// double* A:       A matrix filled out and used to calibrate
// double* T:       A distance matrix T(i,j) = Times[i]-Times[j]
// double* Delta:   A dissimilarity matrix Delta(i,j) = 1 if i > j, 0 otherwise
// double* E:       A matrix filled out and used to calibrate--E(i,j) = exp(-omega*T(i,j))
// double* p:       A probability matrix of cross excitations
// double* p2:      A vector of self-excitation probabilities
// double* ones:    A (size x 1) vector of 1's used in inner products and identity transformations
// double* Times:   A (size x 1) vector of time series data to be calibrated
// int MAX_ITER:    The maximum number of iterations allowed in the calibration
// double* TOL:     The error tolerance or accuracy allowed in the calibration
// double* temp_1:  A (size x 1) temporary vector used in intermediate calculations 
// double* temp_2:  A temporary matrix used in intermediate calculations
// double* temp_3:  A temporary scalar used in intermediate calculations
/******************************************************************************************************/
void calibrate(int size, double *mu, double *mu_t, double *alpha, double *alpha_t, double *omega, double *omega_t, double *A, double *T, double *Delta, double *E, double *p, double *p2, double *D, double* ones, double *Times, int *ctr, double *err, double* temp_1, double* temp_2, double* temp_3)
{       
    //1) (a) Perform inner product to start initial values of mu, alpha, and omega
    inner_product(temp_3, size, Times, ones, temp_1);           // Inner product of Time series
    dim3    dimGrid(1,1,1);
    dim3    dimBlock(1,1,1);
    //assign<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(mu_t,temp_3,1.1,0);      // Assign mu_t to be temp_3*(1/size) (the average)
    //assign<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(alpha_t,temp_3,1.1,0);       // Assign mu_t to be temp_3*(1/size) (the average)
    //assign<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(omega_t,temp_3,1.1,0);       // Assign mu_t to be temp_3*(1/size) (the average)

    /*
    //1) (b) Fill out matrix T of time differences
    dim3    dimGrid((size-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,(size-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,1);
    dim3    dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE,1);
    fill<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size, Times, T); 


    // 2) Fill out matrix E
    dim3    dimGrid((size-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,(size-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,1);
    dim3    dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE,1);
    fill_E<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size, omega, T, E);

    // 3) Update matrix A
    dim3    dimGrid((size-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,(size-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,1);
    dim3    dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE,1);
    scal_mult<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size,size, alpha, delta, A);
    scal_mult<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size,size, omega, A, A);

    dim3    dimGrid((n-1)/TILE_SIZE+1,(m-1)/TILE_SIZE+1,1);
    dim3    dimBlock(TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE,1);
    mysgemm<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size,size,size,A,E,A)


    // 4) Update matrix D 
    mysgemm<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size,size,1,A,ones,D);
    scal_add<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size,size, mu, D, D);

    // 5) Update matrix p and vector p2
    update_p2<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size,mu, D, p2);
    update_p<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size,p2, D, A, p);

    // 6) Update parameters mu, alpha, omega
    inner_product(mu_t, size, p2, ones, temp_1);
    mu_t /=Times[size-1];

    reduction<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(alpha_t,p,size*size);
    alpha_t/= size;

    // Treat T and p as very long vectors and calculate the inner product
    inner_product(omega_t, size*size, T, p, temp_2);
    omega_t = alpha_t/omega_t;  
    */

    // 7) Update error
    dim3 g(100,100,1);
    dim3 b(100,100,1);
    //update<<<g,b>>>(ctr,err,mu,mu_t,alpha,alpha_t,omega,omega_t);

    cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
    if(error != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CUDA error: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(-1);
    }           
}
```

And the following file launches the host code that contains all the kernel calls. 
main.cu (I do not use support.h yet):

```
/******************************************************************************
 *cr
 *cr
 ******************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "kernel.cu"
#include "support.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Timer timer;
    cudaError_t cuda_ret;

    // Initialize host variables ----------------------------------------------

    printf("\nSetting up the problem...\n"); fflush(stdout);
    startTime(&timer);

    double* A_h, *T_h, *Delta_h, *E_h, *p_h, *p2_h, *D_h, *Times_h, *ones_h; 
    double* A_d, *T_d, *Delta_d, *E_d, *p_d, *p2_d, *D_d, *Times_d, *ones_d, *temp_1, *temp_2, *temp_3; 

    double* mu_h, *alpha_h, *omega_h;       // hawkes parameters on host
    double* mu_d, *alpha_d, *omega_d;       // hawkes parameters on device
    double* mu_t_d, *alpha_t_d, *omega_t_d; // hawkes temporary parameters on device

    double* err_h, *err_d;                  // Iterative variables for hohst and device
    int* ctr_h, *ctr_d;                     

    int N;
    unsigned int mat_size, vec_size;

    // Import data
    FILE *fp;
    char str[60];   
    unsigned int count=0;
    double d;

    /* opening file for reading */
    fp = fopen("AAPL_data.txt","r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return(-1);
    }
    while(fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL)
        ++count;    

    // Stick with a limited subset of the data for now to avoid using too much host memory
    N = 1000;

    fclose(fp); 
    printf("Count is %u \n",count);     

    mat_size = N*N;
    vec_size = N;

    dim3 dim_grid, dim_block;

    // Fill matrices with 0's
    A_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*mat_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < mat_size; ++i) { A_h[i] = 0; }

    T_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*mat_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < mat_size; ++i) { T_h[i] = 0; }

    Delta_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*mat_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < mat_size; ++i) { Delta_h[i] = 0; }

    E_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*mat_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < mat_size; ++i) { E_h[i] = 0; }

    p_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*mat_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < mat_size; ++i) { p_h[i] = 0; }

    // Fill vectors with 0's, except the 1's vector
    p2_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*vec_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < vec_size; ++i) { p2_h[i] = 0; }

    Times_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*vec_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < vec_size; ++i) { Times_h[i] = 0; }

    D_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*vec_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < vec_size; ++i) { D_h[i] = 0; }

    ones_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*vec_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < vec_size; ++i) { ones_h[i] = 0; }

    // Start constants as zero
    mu_h    = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double));
    alpha_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double));
    omega_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double));
    err_h   = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double));
    ctr_h   = (int*) malloc( sizeof(int));

    *mu_h = 0;
    *alpha_h = 0;
    *omega_h = 0;
    *err_h = 0;
    *ctr_h = 0;

    // Import data
    count=0;

    /* opening file for reading */
    fp = fopen("AAPL_data.txt","r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return(-1);
    }       
    while(fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL)
    {
        sscanf(str, "%lf", &d);
        if(count < vec_size)
            Times_h[count] = d;
        ++count;
    }       
    fclose(fp); 


    /*printf("TIMES VECTOR: \n");   
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < vec_size; ++i) 
    { 
        printf("TIMES_H[ %u ] is ",i);
        printf("%f \n", Times_h[i]);
    }*/

    printf("Count is %u \n",count);     
    stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));

    // Allocate device variables ----------------------------------------------

    printf("Allocating device variables..."); fflush(stdout);
    startTime(&timer);

    cudaMalloc((void**) &A_d, mat_size*sizeof(double));                     // Create device variable for matrix A  
    cudaMalloc((void**) &T_d, mat_size*sizeof(double));                     // Create device variable for matrix T  
    cudaMalloc((void**) &Delta_d, mat_size*sizeof(double));                 // Create device variable for matrix Delta
    cudaMalloc((void**) &E_d, mat_size*sizeof(double));                     // Create device variable for matrix E
    cudaMalloc((void**) &p_d, mat_size*sizeof(double));                     // Create device variable for matrix p
    cudaMalloc((void**) &p2_d, vec_size*sizeof(double));                    // Create device variable for vector p2
    cudaMalloc((void**) &D_d, vec_size*sizeof(double));                     // Create device variable for vector D
    cudaMalloc((void**) &Times_d, vec_size*sizeof(double));                 // Create device variable for vector Times
    cudaMalloc((void**) &ones_d, vec_size*sizeof(double));                  // Create device variable for vector ones

    // Parameters and intermediate parameters
    cudaMalloc((void**) &mu_d, sizeof(double));                             // Create device variable for constant mu
    cudaMalloc((void**) &alpha_d, sizeof(double));                          // Create device variable for constant alpha
    cudaMalloc((void**) &omega_d, sizeof(double));                          // Create device variable for constant omega
    cudaMalloc((void**) &mu_t_d, sizeof(double));                           // Create device variable for constant mu
    cudaMalloc((void**) &alpha_t_d, sizeof(double));                        // Create device variable for constant alpha
    cudaMalloc((void**) &omega_t_d, sizeof(double));                        // Create device variable for constant omega

    // Temporary variables
    cudaMalloc((void**) &temp_1, vec_size*sizeof(double));                  // Create device variable for constant omega
    cudaMalloc((void**) &temp_2, mat_size*sizeof(double));                  // Create device variable for constant omega
    cudaMalloc((void**) &temp_3, sizeof(double));                           // Create device variable for constant omega

    // Iteration variables
    cudaMalloc((void**) &err_d, sizeof(double));                            // Create device variable for iterative counters
    cudaMalloc((void**) &ctr_d, sizeof(int));

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));

    // Copy host variables to device ------------------------------------------

    printf("Copying data from host to device..."); fflush(stdout);
    startTime(&timer);

    cudaMemcpy(A_d,A_h,mat_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);            // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(T_d,T_h,mat_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);            // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(Delta_d,Delta_h,mat_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);    // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(E_d,E_h,mat_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);            // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(p_d,p_h,mat_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);            // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(p2_d,p2_h,vec_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);          // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(D_d,D_h,vec_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);            // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(ones_d,ones_h,vec_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);      // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(Times_d,Times_h,vec_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);    // Copy from host var to device var

    // Parameters and intermediate parameters
    cudaMemcpy(mu_d,mu_h,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);                   // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(alpha_d,alpha_h,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);             // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(omega_d,omega_h,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);             // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(mu_t_d,mu_h,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);                 // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(alpha_t_d,alpha_h,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);               // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(omega_t_d,omega_h,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);               // Copy from host var to device var

    // Temporary variables
    cudaMemcpy(temp_1,D_h,vec_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);         // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(temp_2,A_h,mat_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);         // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(temp_3,mu_h,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);                 // Copy from host var to device var

    // Iteration variables
    cudaMemcpy(err_d,err_h,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);                 // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(ctr_d,ctr_h,sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);                    // Copy from host var to device var

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));

    // Launch kernel using standard sgemm interface ---------------------------
    printf("Launching kernel..."); fflush(stdout);
    startTime(&timer);

    int MAX_ITER = 100;
    double TOL = .001;

    //while(ctr_h < MAX_ITER && err_h < TOL)
    //{
        calibrate(vec_size,mu_d, mu_t_d, alpha_d, alpha_t_d, omega_d, omega_t_d, A_d, T_d, Delta_d, E_d, p_d, 
            p2_d, D_d, ones_d, Times_d, ctr_d, err_d, temp_1, temp_2, temp_3);

    //  cudaMemcpy(err_h,err_d,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);     // Copy from device var to host var
    //  cudaMemcpy(ctr_h,ctr_d,sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);        // Copy from device var to host var
    //}

    cuda_ret = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if(cuda_ret != cudaSuccess) FATAL("Unable to launch kernel");
    stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));

    // Copy device variables from host ----------------------------------------

    printf("Copying data from device to host...\n"); fflush(stdout);
    startTime(&timer);


    cudaMemcpy(mu_h,mu_d,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);       // Copy from device var to host var
    cudaMemcpy(alpha_h,alpha_d,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); // Copy from device var to host var
    cudaMemcpy(omega_h,omega_d,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); // Copy from device var to host var

    printf("mu is %f: \n",*mu_h);
    printf("alpha is %f: \n",*alpha_h);
    printf("omega is %f: \n",*omega_h);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));


    // Free memory ------------------------------------------------------------

    free(A_h);
    free(T_h);
    free(Delta_h);
    free(E_h);
    free(p_h);
    free(p2_h);
    free(D_h);
    free(ones_h);
    free(Times_h);
    free(mu_h);
    free(alpha_h);
    free(omega_h);

    cudaFree(A_d);
    cudaFree(T_d);
    cudaFree(Delta_d);
    cudaFree(E_d);
    cudaFree(p_d);
    cudaFree(p2_d);
    cudaFree(D_d);
    cudaFree(ones_d);
    cudaFree(Times_d);
    cudaFree(mu_d);
    cudaFree(alpha_d);
    cudaFree(omega_d);

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error CUDA error: invalid configuration argument from the cudaGetLastError() call at the end of kernel.cu. Since everything is commented out except the inner_product host function that calls two kernels, I assume the problem is coming from there:

```
/****************************************************************/
// Uses several kernels to compute the inner product of A and B
void inner_product(double *out, int m, const double *A, const double* B, double* temp)
{
    dim3    dimGrid((m-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,(m-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,1);
    dim3    dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE,1);

    elem_mul<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(m,A,B,temp);
    reduction<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(out,temp,m);        
}
/****************************************************************/
```

Since the m passed is 1000 and BLOCK_SIZE is 512, this should produce dimGrid(1,1,1) and dimBlock(512,512,1), but this is giving the above error. Even when I changed this to dimBlock(256,256,1) I got the same error. I am pretty sure block sizes of up to 1024 threads are allowed for this device.

Comment: Is this code avalible somewhere, since you basicly provided most of the parts? I would need it for fast hawke's calibration for academic proposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your block dimenion `dimBlock(512,512)` is to big! There is a maximum count of threads per thread block that can be launched, depending on the compute architecture of your gpu.

There are several ways how to find out what the maximum block dimensions are.
A fast way is to use from the cuda sdk samples the [deviceQuery](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/#device-query) program. That lists all informations of your cuda-enabled gpus, such like the maximum block dimensions.
Or you use [cuda occupancy calculator](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls) and try to input your kernel parameters. In your example there will be a error.
A third way is to read the [cuda programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__feature-support-per-compute-capability) where you can find all the informations that you need.

Comment: Because this till to much threads per block (65536). Depending on your hardware only 1024 or 1536 threads could be grouped into a thread block!

Answer (score -1):

This might help to dynamically define the number of threads you want to use.

```
struct cudaDeviceProp properties;
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&properties, device);
cout<<"using "<<properties.multiProcessorCount<<" multiprocessors"<<endl;
cout<<"max threads per processor: "<<properties.maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor<<endl<<endl;
```

You can use any configuration of:

1. dim3(iThreadsPerBlock)
2. dim3(iThreadsPerBlockX, iThreadsPerBlockY)
3. dim3(iThreadsPerBlockX, iThreadsPerBlockY, iThreadsPerBlockZ)

where the volume of your block does not exceed properties.maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor

Comment: You are mistaken.  Have you actually tried this?  maxThreadsPerMultiprocessor is not the limit of the `dim3` variables you are suggesting.

Comment: I did not say it is the limit, but it is probably what you want to use in order to have an optimized code. Also the warp size is important.

Comment: `maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor` is a number like 1536 or 2048 (look it up!).  Your block cannot consist of 1536 or 2048 threads.  Those are illegal threadblock sizes.